# Mapping unique combinations to numbers

Tags: string, permutation

I am trying to come up with a solution to a problem I thought of. I have the number of permutations of 26 characters with 6 possible spots as 26^6 = 308 915 776. I was trying to make a way so that I could map each number to a unique combination and be able to go back and forth from combination to number.

```
An example:
1 = aaaaaa
2 = aaaaab
27 = aaaaba
```

Is it possible to write a polynomial time algorithm that would convert between the two and/or are there any efficient examples of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just base conversion my friend.

Since you didn't specify a language, the following is pseudo-code with array indexing and string indexing starting at 0 and assignment is :=.

if you let 'a' be 0, and 'z' be 25, then to convert from base 26 to base 10:

```
total:= 0
loop index from 0 to 5
  temp:= 'z' - input[index]  // Left to right. Single base 26 digit to base 10
  total:= 26 * total + temp    // Shift left and add the converted digit
  increment index and goto loop start
```

To go back to letters (base 26) is also easy:

```
result:= ''
loop index from 0 to 5
  temp:= 'a' + input mod 26  // Input modulus 26 is the base 26 digit to add next
  result:= temp + result  // Append current result to the new base 26 digit
  input:= input div 26  // Divide input by 26, throw away the remainder
  increment index and goto loop start
```

If you want all a's to be 1, then add one after converting from base 26 to base 10 and subtract 1 before converting from base 10 to base 26.  Personally, I'd let all a's be 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could map it via pointers into a double:

```
char *example = "abcdef";

double d = 0;
char *p = (char *)&d;
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    p[i] = example[i];

// d is your code
```

It's not so beautiful and not 100% allowed, but it works.